# What are the specific criteria I should consider when choosing a Java Barcoding Library and which ones do you recommend?

Tags: java, barcode, barcode4j, barbecue

It's 2015 and the last time this question was asked was 2009, and Sourceforge.net is currently down, so I'm having a hard time researching the different Java implementations of barcoding libraries to decide what the best fit would be for our organization.

Barcode4J and Barbecue seem to be the two hot ones out right now so I'm paying attention to those.

Flexibility is the key requirement for our organization: we need to support a variety of customers that may have different printers, size requirements, etc. Most of our barcodes will probably just embed the internal database id for several of our data types, but there may be a few barcodes that need to accommodate more complex amounts of data.

Comment: Which barcode types do you need to produce? It is 2015, therefore Sourceforge.net might be not the appropriate place to look for libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Apart of the libs you mentioned yourself [zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) is not only a reader but also a good generator for a lot of barcode types.